# NSIS GetParent functon throws an unknown error

Tags: installation, nsis

In my NSIS installer script I am trying to use the **GetParent** macro defined in **FileFunc.nsh** but I get a strange error. Anybody a clue why?

Here is my script code

```
!include "FileFunc.nsh"

Section
   ${GetParent} "$INSTDIR" $parentDir
SectionEnd
```

And the error I get is:

```
!insertmacro: GetParentCall
Usage: Pop $(user_var: output)
Error in macro GetParentCall on macroline 5
```

I am using NSIS 2.46

Comment: 2.46 is old, upgrade to v3 or at least 2.51!

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I am forced to use this version (legacy code project).

Comment: 2.51 should be fully compatible with 2.46.

Comment: Most probably (afaik for v3.x the API didn't change either) but changing the version just before production release is still too risky (if something breaks I am held responsible). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$parentDir` variable has not been declared, try:

```
!include "FileFunc.nsh"
Var parentDir    

Section
   ${GetParent} "$INSTDIR" $parentDir
SectionEnd
```

Only $0..$9, $R0..$R9 and a handful of other ($instdir etc.) documented variables exist by default.

Comment: Ah! Thanks that makes totally sense. Will get back with an answer (and upvote) if it worked once I am back in the office but that looks like it's the culprit. Doh!

Comment: Cheers for the help!